# Detect whether clang is compiling using c++11 or legacy libstdc++ standard library

Tags: xcode, c++11, clang

I've got an Xcode project that I'm migrating to use with clang's option `-stdlib libc++`, to enable C++11 support. Some of my source files need to know which library is being used, for instance so that I do things like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CPP11_LIB_SUPPORT
  #include <memory>
#else 
  #include <tr1/memory>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_CPP11_LIB_SUPPORT
  vector.emplace_back(newValue);
#else 
  vector.push_back(newValue);
#endif
```

I'm having trouble though finding the preprocessor macros (if indeed there are any) that are set for this option.  I've tried dumping the outputs of clang with:

```
clang -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

to compare with:

```
clang -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

but this gives the same results.  Note that I don't want to switch on whether we're using the c++11 *language* setting, but whether we're using the c++11 *library*.  Is there any reliable way of detecting this in the code?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any sure way that is guaranteed to be portable, but this is what I use for now:

```
// libc++ detected:     _LIBCPP_VERSION
// libstdc++ detected:  __GLIBCXX__
#if defined(__clang__)
#   if __has_include(<__config>) // defines _LIBCPP_VERSION
#       include <__config>
#   elif __has_include(<bits/c++config.h>) // defines __GLIBCXX__
#       include <bits/c++config.h>
#   else
#       include <ios>
#   endif
#elif defined(__GNUC__) // gcc does not have __has_include
#   include <ios> // ios should include the c++config.h which defines __GLIBCXX__
#endif
```

It's not great, but works for me for now.

libc++ defines `_LIBCPP_VERSION` and stdc++ defines `__GLIBCXX__` which is nice, but unfortunately these macros are not defined by the compiler. Instead, they're defined in a non-standard header file, and you cannot test their definition unless that header has been included.

Note: Apparently stdc++ defined `__GLIBCPP__` in older versions instead. Since you require c++11, this isn't going to be a problem.

<strike>Clang</strike> (Edit: Standard since C++17) has a nice feature `__has_include` which can be used to test for these but if neither header is found, the macro falls back to just including a standard header which hopefully uses the internal header under the hood. I have `<ios>` here, but the choice of standard header to include is up to you. You can look for headers that include the internal header with something like (this is for gcc on linux):

```
grep -Rl '#include <bits/c++config.h>' /usr/include/c++
```

Pick any header that you're likely to use in the project anyway.

Since this isn't guaranteed to work for any given past or future compiler/standard library version, I wouldn't rely on these defines for anything but optional features like:

```
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
    std::set_terminate(__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler);
#endif
```

Comment: Aha, that's quite a sophisticated series of checks. Neat, but I think it might be overkill for my requirements, so I might have to find a more pragmatic way of dealing with it

Comment: I suppose that you can leave that "if defined" thing out completely, and still check for the given defines as long as you've included a header from the standard library. I use this *just to be sure* (with very loose definition of *sure*).

Comment: This check has a number of problems, the biggest being the use of the internal headers only meant for use by the implementation. GCC does support `__has_include` these days, and so do other compilers. You could have made your checks future-proof by doing `#ifdef __has_include` so it would work with any compiler that supports it. You could also have simply included a lightweight standard header file such as `<iosfwd>` to check for the `_LIBCPP_VERSION` or `__GLIBCXX__` macros, and not rely on the internal headers.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Good points. I think my reasoning was that I couldn't find documentation for a guarantee that `_LIBCPP_VERSION` would be included in standard headers, so I preferred to find the file that defines it. I suppose I did same for `__GLIBCXX__` for consitency. I also believed that there be no problem in softly depending on the internal headers, since the `__has_include` would give me a fallback in case they were missing in a future version. Since answering I've discovered Boost Predef, and I wouldn't bother writing these checks myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef __has_include
# if __has_include(<ciso646>)
#  include <ciso646>
#  if defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION)
#   define USING_LIBCPP 1
#  endif
# endif
#endif

#if !USING_LIBCPP
# define USING_LIBSTDCXX 1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing these kinds of checks I suggest you choose a compiler/library version and require that or newer. It makes no sense to half-use C++11 library features. On Mac OS X, just require compilation with `clang++ -stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: In an ideal world that would be the case. As it stands we're in the middle of a larger C++11 migration with legacy code considerations which means it's Not Quite That Simple

Comment: Although I can understand there might be reasons for this, I can't see what is preventing you from using libc++ exclusively, for everything. It can even be used in C++03 mode.

Comment: The problem is that we want to be able to use C++11 language features (eg auto, enum class) but we're not able to switch to the C++11 library. I'm working on the migration and want to ensure that we can build with libc++ or libstdc++

Answer (score 0):

I use next code:

```
#include <cstddef> // for __GLIBCXX__

#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
#  include <tr1/memory>
#else
#  include <memory>
#endif
```

[source](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/05/24/smart-pointers-in-boost-tr1-cxx-x0/)